# Windows 8.1 takes two minutes to open This PC or File Explorer - very slow

Tags: windows-8.1

When I attempt to open "This PC" or anything using windows file explorer it opens a white window and minutes later it's usable. I've already tried running sfc/scannow as an admin, and it didn't find anything wrong. What should I do about this? This is a clean, fresh 8.1 install. Everything else is flawless.

edit: I've discovered that I have a lot of Windows updates to download - that's probably the issue. However I can't seem to download any of them. When I get it going it says "Downloading 74 Updates," but "0 KB total, 0% complete" for as long as I let it run. Anyone have experience with a non-updating Windows?

Comment: What's your hardware? Have you installed all drivers? Is the system up to date and Windows Update shows no updates available?

Comment: It's hard to say, because settings etc. also will not run. I am unfamiliar with Win8.1 - do you check for updates through the settings menu (gear)? Clicking on that doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Comment: You can try a clean boot using msconfig.exe (built in windows feature). If the behavior(s) does not occur anymore, start enabling the disabled autoruns till it comes again. Check the last enabled autorun. A viruscheck and / or running [ccleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) may also be helpfull

Comment: Just let the WindowsUpdate run. Updates will be installed eventually.

Comment: Is there a network drive connected, which does not exist? Is there an external USB drive, which is broken?

Comment: Stop realtime protection of Windows Defender. Is this better?

Answer (score 0):

Re: Windows 8 Update, there have been a few issues with the update process that Microsoft has acknowledged and for which it has released patches and notes. See the following MS links:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Open-the-Windows-Update-troubleshooter
http://support2.microsoft.com/gp/windows-update-issues/en-za
See also: https://www.winhelp.us/reinstall-windows-update.html

In addition, the progress indicator on Windows 8 updates is erratic -- on one PC I have (HP), no progress is shown, but update eventually competes. On another (Toshiba), it work as expected.

One *caveat*: Windows Update expects certain folders and files, particularly in the path C:\Users\Bart\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Utilities\Programs [All Users]. After I made the mistake of deleting some, I found update failed until they were restored.